# A word or phrase meaning familial relationship in a workplace, but no nepotism

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Suppose there are two family members working in the same place, hired and retained through their own merit.  (That is not nepotism.)  Is there a word or phrase that can get the situation across succinctly?

Comment: Related co-workers (or colleagues). You may have to clarify "related".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Incidentally***, they are related (as so-and-so).

ODO:

> **[incidentally](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incidentally)** 
>   *ADVERB*
>
> **1** [SENTENCE ADVERB] Used to add a further comment or a remark unconnected to the current subject; by the way: incidentally, it was
>   many months before the whole truth was discovered
>
> **2** In an incidental manner; as a chance occurrence: the infection was discovered only incidentally at post-mortem examination